# How to change the DisplayName of a table in ASP.Net Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm new to Dynamic Data. I want to change the DisplayName of tables in Default.aspx page so I can set meaning full names for them. Also I want to change column names of tables when I List, Edit and Insert mode. How can I do that in c# language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by setting the `DisplayName` (from `System.ComponentModel`) attribute on each table. For this you'll need a partial class for each table that you're scaffolding with Dynamic Data e.g.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;

...

[ScaffoldTable(true)]
[DisplayName("Northwind Products")]
partial class Product
{
}
```

renders...

[image]

Comment: How about column name? When I use DisplayName for a table column I get this error "Attribute 'DisplayName' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, method, property, indexer, event' declarations"

Comment: Solved. Just add {get; set;} in front of column name. [DisplayName("Active")]
    public object IsActive { get; set; }

Comment: This doesn't work for Foreign key columns. Do you know how to change the name of Foreign keys?

Comment: @Karadous Have a look at the `DisplayColumn` attribute in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, it lets you select the column from the referenced table to display

Comment: It doesn't work for foreign keys or it is better to say I don't know how to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else seeing this post I had the same requirements as the original poster.   I tried the suggestions and these still didn't work.   I found out (this might be obvious) that you need to ensure you have a "namespace" declaration in your partial class.  The namespace needs to be the same as the entity model you are using i.e. under App_Code you should have a Model.designer.cs file - your namespace needs to be the same as