# Is it possible to change the display name of EntitySet fields?

Tags: asp.net-dynamic-data

Every foreign key is defined as a EntitySet in Dynamic Data. Is it possible to change the display name of these EntitySet fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of poster's same question from 10 days earlier, answered similarly : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511433

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Suppose you have a Course with a foreign key CourseType.  You can apply the DisplayAttribute to courses:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CourseMetadata))]
[DisplayName("Courses")]
public partial class Course 
{}

public class CourseMetadata
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public object CourseTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Course Type")]
    public object CourseType { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is CourseTypeId the name of FK and CourseType the name of child table?

Comment: Each Course has a CourseType and the Course table has a CourseTypeId column.  the CourseType table has an Id PK column (keyed to Course.CourseTypeId) and a Name column.

Comment: I found the answer.                                                   [Display(Name="Course Type")]                                    public EntityRef<CourseType> CourseType{get; set;}                 this solution solved my problrm.

Comment: Which is what I suggested above ;>

Comment: No Ash. "public object" didn't work. I used "public EntityRef" instead. ;)

Comment: I wasn't trying to write your code for you, I was trying to point out the DisplayAttribute for you with an example.